# How can I get UI element over which pointer is in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, mouseover

I can detect if mouse is hovering any UI element by `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`.

But how do I know which `GameObjest` it is exactly?

I have tried:

```
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        foreach (GameObject go in new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current).hovered)
            print(go.name);
```

But in every moment `new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current).hovered` is empty whether I hover or not.

I can see required info using `print(EventSystem.current);`:

```
<b>Selected:</b>


<b>Pointer Input Module of type: </b>UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule
<B>Pointer:</b> -1
<b>Position</b>: (746.0, 535.0)
<b>delta</b>: (60.0, -44.0)
<b>eligibleForClick</b>: False
<b>pointerEnter</b>: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
<b>pointerPress</b>: 
<b>lastPointerPress</b>: 
<b>pointerDrag</b>: 
<b>Use Drag Threshold</b>: True
<b>Current Rayast:</b>
Name: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
module: Name: Canvas (UnityEngine.GameObject)
eventCamera: 
sortOrderPriority: 0
renderOrderPriority: 0
module camera: null
distance: 0
index: 0
depth: 1
worldNormal: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
worldPosition: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
screenPosition: (746.0, 535.0)
module.sortOrderPriority: 0
module.renderOrderPriority: 0
sortingLayer: 0
sortingOrder: 0
<b>Press Rayast:</b>


<B>Pointer:</b> -2
<b>Position</b>: (746.0, 535.0)
<b>delta</b>: (60.0, -44.0)
<b>eligibleForClick</b>: False
<b>pointerEnter</b>: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
<b>pointerPress</b>: 
<b>lastPointerPress</b>: 
<b>pointerDrag</b>: 
<b>Use Drag Threshold</b>: True
<b>Current Rayast:</b>
Name: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
module: Name: Canvas (UnityEngine.GameObject)
eventCamera: 
sortOrderPriority: 0
renderOrderPriority: 0
module camera: null
distance: 0
index: 0
depth: 1
worldNormal: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
worldPosition: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
screenPosition: (746.0, 535.0)
module.sortOrderPriority: 0
module.renderOrderPriority: 0
sortingLayer: 0
sortingOrder: 0
<b>Press Rayast:</b>


<B>Pointer:</b> -3
<b>Position</b>: (746.0, 535.0)
<b>delta</b>: (60.0, -44.0)
<b>eligibleForClick</b>: False
<b>pointerEnter</b>: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
<b>pointerPress</b>: 
<b>lastPointerPress</b>: 
<b>pointerDrag</b>: 
<b>Use Drag Threshold</b>: True
<b>Current Rayast:</b>
Name: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)
module: Name: Canvas (UnityEngine.GameObject)
eventCamera: 
sortOrderPriority: 0
renderOrderPriority: 0
module camera: null
distance: 0
index: 0
depth: 1
worldNormal: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
worldPosition: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
screenPosition: (746.0, 535.0)
module.sortOrderPriority: 0
module.renderOrderPriority: 0
sortingLayer: 0
sortingOrder: 0
<b>Press Rayast:</b>
```

By the way why are there 3 pointers (-1, -2, -3) and what does this mean? I've read somewhere in docs, `pointer -1` is left mouse button, but I click nothing, so this is weird.

I can see `<b>pointerEnter</b>: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)` and `Name: cursorInfoText (UnityEngine.GameObject)` which is what I need.
But how do I extract this info? I have tried `print(new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current).pointerEnter);`, but it is `Null` doesn't matter I enter or hover. And I see no other appropriate methods or properties in docs, although I can see that info is stored. What have I missed?

My goal is to detect if mouse is hovering UI element with some conditions (ignore small amount of UI elements (likely by tag) and don't ignore the rest (most of elements)), so I have to get `GameObject` itself. And if mouse doesn't hover UI element (except those few), script does unrelated to UI stuff. But do not ignore if it hovers one of those few and one of the rest at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

> But how do I know which GameObjest it is exactly?

You are looking for `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject`.

Like this:

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse Over: " + EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name);
}
```

**Check By tag**:

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.CompareTag("yourTagName"))
{

}
```

Or with `IPointerEnterHandler` and `eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast`:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class Test : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Mouse Over: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've forgotten to mention I've tried `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` too and it is always return `Null` as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Necronomicron That's fine. I provided an answer with 2 solutions. Why n not use the second method? That's actually the way to do this. I am talking about the answer with `IPointerEnterHandler`.

Comment: I am just getting to the core of the 2nd solution, but I wonder why are there `Null`s everywhere in the 1st?

Comment: You tried the second solution and there's null everywhere? Did you copy it exactly as it is?....with the `if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject != null)`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried 2nd solution yet, I am talking about 1st solution and about my own attempts as well.

Comment: Oh. Make sure that `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name` is put into `if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())`. That may be why. It works for me here with Unity 5.4. You can also check for null with `if(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject !=null )` then use it. If that doesn't work, go with solution 2.

Comment: I did. But 5.4? Beta release? Because I can see only 5.3.6 on Unity page, I'm using 5.3.4 now though.

Comment: Yes. beta release which will be released this month. 5.4.0F1 http://unity3d.com/unity/beta.

Comment: Should I attach that script to **each** UI element? Or how do I use this? I've tried to add these strings to my current script and it gives no effect.

Comment: No. For your Unity version, just attach it to the parent `Canvas` that contains the UI you want to detect mouse-over on. On Unity 5.4.0F1, you can attach it on any GameObject and it will still work. Also after restarting Unity, `currentSelectedGameObject` stopped working. I came to conclusion that it working in the first place is a bug. That is only meant to work with OnMouseDown not mouse over. So, it shouldn't work for you. The second solution should. Happy coding!

Comment: Well, it sends message only on enter, but I need to receive messages on hover.

Comment: What do you mean? OnPointerEnter means mouse over which the-same as hover. If you put your mouse over the UI Image, OnPointerEnter will be called. What problem aare you having wit the second solution?

Comment: I need to receive message each frame while mouse is over any UI element, not just first frame. It also returns only on object, even if I enter several elements at the same frame.

Comment: As far as I know `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` only return anything if the ui element is selected and they can only be selected if clicked on them

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for a similar case:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class whatever : MonoBehaviour
{    
    private void Update()
    {
        Rect position = this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetGlobalPosition();
        if (position.Contains(Input.mousePosition)) Debug.Log("Yes, it is");

        if(this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().isMouseOverUI()) Debug.Log("It still is");
    }
}


namespace UnityEngine
{
    namespace UI
    {
        public static class ExtensionMethods
        {
            public static Rect GetGlobalPosition(this RectTransform rectTransform)
            {
                Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
                rectTransform.GetWorldCorners(corners);
                return new Rect(corners[0].x, corners[0].y, corners[2].x - corners[0].x, corners[2].y - corners[0].y);
            }

            public static bool isMouseOverUI(this RectTransform rectTransform)
            {
                Rect position = rectTransform.GetGlobalPosition();
                return position.Contains(Input.mousePosition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically what I did is I created an extension method for getting any UI's RectTransform position. Now I am able to ask if the mouse is hovering that UI element right now or not. So for example what you could do is create an array/list and check for every element of that list if the mouse is currently hovering it (isMouseOverUI).

I know this is not the perfectly solution you desired but I hope it might help.