# How to ignore certain types of UI elements or use MouseButtonDown for layer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

All my game is made by UI. I have some function called when i press left mouse button. But it also react for UI button clicks, so i want to check if i click on UI element or not, and than decide what to do. I found that
`EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject()`
can help, but, as i said - all my game made of UI elements, so, if i use it - i cant do anything in scene. Is there a way to point which exactly elements shoul it ignore? Buttons for example. Or is there a way to call `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` only for certain layer?

Comment: Would this answer your question [How can I get UI element over which pointer is in Unity3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539593/how-can-i-get-ui-element-over-which-pointer-is-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html

put your buttons and anything else that you don't want to call your function in a separate layer

```
public LayerMask clickable;//exclude the button layers here

GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
PointerEventData m_PointerEventData;
EventSystem m_EventSystem;

void Awake(){
    m_Raycaster = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GraphicRaycaster>();
    m_EventSystem = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>();
}

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            //Set up the new Pointer Event
            m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(m_EventSystem);
            //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the mouse position
            m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

            //Create a list of Raycast Results
            List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

            //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and mouse click position
            m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);

            foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
            {
                //is the layer of the gameObject hit included in clickable?
                if(clickable == (clickable | (1 << result.gameObject.layer))) {
                    doYourFunction();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
}
```